# Just recently started getting shocked in the shower

Tags: electrical

About a week and a half ago I started getting shocked from the upstairs shower head, the downstairs sink faucet, and the the tub spout, I leaned back when I was taking a bath touched the spout with my head and that's when I felt it. It doesn't happen every time. I asked a buddy to come check it out. He turned on the sink faucet ( nothing ) put his hand in the water then touched the faucets  ( nothing  ). He checked the connections on the bonding cables, H/W tank  and water meter, outside grounding rod. Found a corroded connection at the box ground to street side of water meter. Pulled it and put it under the clamp of the street side of meter. Felt the shock two days later. He checked Voltage between the neutral and the street side of the water pipe and got a reading of 0.045 v. Did the same on the house side of the pipe and got a lower voltage. Could this be a sign that the shock voltage is coming from outside the house? He checked neutral to the ground line coming into the box from ground rod and I think he said it was lower than that of the street side pipe voltage. Any insight into testing to see if its coming in through the pipes would be appreciated.

Comment: Regardless of any fixes, please STOP using these fixtures immediately!  What you have is an extremely dangerous situation where you or someone else could be severely injured or killed.  This is not a situation where a "quick and dirty" fix is called for.  The cause needs to be investigated and properly corrected before your shower and other fixtures are safe to use.

Comment: It sounds like his buddy knew what he was doing. I would be looking at leakage at the water heater , I have measured many grounding systems and regularly find high impedance on single grounds that were properly made and to code.

Comment: Thanks for the information but I'm trying to finure out what's putting a charge on the pipe. It's a gas water heater.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read about the military personnel that were electrocuted in the shower in Afghanistan or Iraq about 15 to 20 years ago? It is caused by the piping not being properly *bonded* to the grounding system.

So take the advice of jwh20 and get a professional over there and find whats wrong and repair it.

**This is not a DIY project.**